# C Program Omitting Characters

Tags: c

I am trying to create a program that converts a text file into c, just for the fun of it. My issue is that the output value is different than what it should be.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


     FILE *intf=fopen(argv[1], "r");        //input and output file
     FILE *ocf=fopen(argv[2], "w");
     char b[1000];
     char *d;
     char *s;
     char *token;

    const char delim [2] = "`";

        fprintf(ocf, "#include <stdio.h>\n int main(void) {\n"); //Preparation

    while (fgets(b, 20, intf) !=NULL) { //Ensure that EOF has not been reached

      if (d = strstr(b, "print")) { //Search for "print" in the file
          fprintf(ocf, "printf(\"");    //Prepare for "printf("");" statement
          s=strstr(b, "`");     //Search for delimiting character
          token=strtok(s, delim);       //Omit delimiting character
    while( token != NULL) {
            token[strlen(token)-1]=NULL;    //Omit newline character that kept geting inserted
            fprintf(ocf, "%s", token);  //Print what was read
            token = strtok(NULL, delim);    //
    }
        fprintf(ocf, "\");\n");     //Finish printf() statement
    }

    }
      fprintf(ocf, "\n}");      //Finish c file
      printf("Creation of c file complete \n");
    }
```

The input file:

```
    print `hello\n world
    print `Have a nice day
```

And the output:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(void) {
    printf("hello\n wor");
    printf("Have a nice");

    }
```

Could someone advise me on what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code, to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should fix this line:

```
while (fgets(b, 20, intf) !=NULL)
```

It actually gets up to 20 chars from the line, so you don't read the whole lines. Then the rest of the line is read in the next iteration, but it's skipped since it doesn't contain word "print". You should get more than 20 characters per line to fix this error. Your buffer (b) is of the size 1000, so you can afford it.

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. I thought I was using strtok incorrectly.